# org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Too many arguments to function 'IF'. At most 3 were expected but got 5

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi, jxls

I'm new to JXLS library. Inside Jx:each area, I am using IF statement in a cell, K36, which is referencing a cell J36: $[IF("${account.type}"="Cash Flow", J36, 0)]
when i run the template i'm getting error : 2023-03-23 12:02:33,566 ERROR [org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer(https-openssl-nio-8445-exec-7)] - Failed to set formula = IF("Cash Flow"="Cash Flow", J44,J63,J82, 0) into cell = 'Journal Entries'!K44
org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Too many arguments to function 'IF'. At most 3 were expected but got 5.

I'm trying to find if this even allowed if yes how to fix this error.

I tried several combinations for IF statement, listing few below, but non of them work. J36 is a sum of other cells.

```
$[IF("${account.type}"="Cash Flow", SUM(E36:I36), 0)]
$[IF("${account.type}"="Cash Flow", SUM(E36, F36, H36 + I36, 0)]
$[IF("${account.type}"="Cash Flow", (J36), 0)]
$[IF("${account.type}"="Cash Flow", $J36, 0)]
$[IF("${account.type}"="Cash Flow", {J36}, 0)]
$[IF("${account.type}"="Cash Flow", ${J36}, 0)]
```

Comment: If you create a file in Excel with that formula, and read it back with Apache POI, what did Excel transform that formula into in the file?

Comment: When the Apache POI creates the excel transformed file, I get : 
= IF("Cash Flow"="Cash Flow", J44,J63,J82, 0) When the input is : $[IF("${account.type}"="Cash Flow", J36, 0)]
I want = IF("Cash Flow"="Cash Flow", J44, 0) for next jx:each iteration and = IF("Cash Flow"="Cash Flow", J63, 0) for next iteration. not sure why i'm getting all the possible iterated cells (J44,J63,J82) in each iteration.